# Show that $m\mathbb{Z}$ is a normal subgroup of $n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory

Let $n,m \ge 1$ such that $n|m$. Suppose $m\mathbb{Z} < n\mathbb{Z}$

Show that $m\mathbb{Z}$ is a normal subgroup of $n\mathbb{Z}$

**My attempt at solving the question**

$\forall x \in m\mathbb{Z}$, $\forall y \in n\mathbb{Z}$ Let us show: $yxy^{-1} \in m\mathbb{Z}$

for $c, d, e \in \mathbb{Z}$:

$y=cn$, $x=dm=d(en)$

Therefore: $yxy^{-1} = ydmy^{-1}$

$y$ and $y^{-1}$ $\in \mathbb{Z}$

Therefore $ydmy^{-1} \in m\mathbb{Z}$ therefore 
$yxy^{-1} \in m\mathbb{Z}$

Therefore $m\mathbb{Z}$ is a normal subgroup of $n\mathbb{Z}$

**Is that the right approach to the problem ?**

Comment: There's a much easier proof using a result concerning abelian groups.

Comment: I edited my solution

Comment: At the very beginning, finish by saying $yxy^{-1}=x$. "Subgroup" takes a line or two, though strangely the problem supposes  it.

Comment: Is there anything to show ? Any subgroup of an abelian group is normal.